# PDE's: Laplace's Equation in 2-dimensions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

Okay so, I've completed the problem up as far as part (d), where it specifies a new boundary condition and asks to re-solve with the other 3 conditions left the same.

Taking what I have from before I get the following:

$$u(x,0) = g(x)=\sum E_{N}Sin\left(\frac{N\pi x}{a}\right)$$

but the I run into the problem with f(x), as it ends up being:

$$u(x,b) = f(x) = \sum\left(E_{N}Cosh\left(\frac{N\pi b}{a}\right)+F_{N}Sinh\left(\frac{N\pi b}{a}\right)\right)Sin\left(\frac{N\pi x}{a}\right)$$

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?

Also, should have mentioned that my u(x,y) for the first part was:

$$u(x,y) = \sum E_{N}Sinh\left(\frac{N\pi y}{a}\right)Sin\left(\frac{N\pi x}{a}\right)$$

Where $E_{N}$ is a fourier coefficient.

Thank you!

Also, all summations are over N from N=1 to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You know that all solutions to your PDE satisfying the left and right boundary conditions are of the form

$$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cosh(n \pi y/a) + b_n \sinh(n \pi y/a)) \sin(n \pi x/a)$$

for some $a_n,b_n$. To satisfy the top and bottom boundary conditions, you should choose $a_n,b_n$ such that

$$u(x,0)=g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(n \pi x/a)$$

and

$$u(x,b)=f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cosh(n \pi b/a) + b_n \sinh(n \pi b/a)) \sin(n \pi x/a).$$

Now for each $n$ you get two linear equations in the two unknowns $a_n,b_n$, via the Fourier coefficients of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Still not quite sure what you mean, could you elaborate a bit further please?

Comment: There are numbers $d_n,e_n$ such that $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d_n \sin(n \pi x/a)$ and $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e_n \sin(n \pi x/a)$. These numbers should be equal to the coefficients appearing in these two representations of $g$ and $f$. So in particular $a_n=d_n$, but now $b_n$ will wind up being defined by a slightly complicated expression involving both $d_n$ and $e_n$.